# jQuery onclick on alert close button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to fire off some code when the x at the top right of an alert box is pressed.

I am using jquery built in dialog box.  I can see the element in developer tools in chrome but dont see an ID I can reference to be used in onclick?

```
<a href="#" class="ui-dialog-titlebar-close ui-corner-all" role="button">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick">close</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Try getting a reference to the button using a class selector?

Comment: i tried '$("#ui-dialog-titlebar-close ui-corner-all").click(function()'

Comment: @DocHoliday, your selector is wrong, there is more than just id selector. read about CSS selectors.

Comment: @DocHoliday `$("#ui..")` is id selector, `$(".ui...")` is class selector.

Comment: ahhhhh I see where I messed up...I was getting ID selector....thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery `.on()`. Select the `.ui-icon.ui-icon-closethick` element within a titlebar, in case you use the icon somewhere else.

You must use **.** instead of **#** to select an element by **class**, otherwise, the `#` is used to select an element by its **id** attribute..

### JavaScript/jQuery

```js
$('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close .ui-icon.ui-icon-closethick').on('click', function () {
    alert("test");
});
```

### [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lun471k/SSCnh/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a.ui-dialog-titlebar-close span.ui-icon-closethick').on('click', function() {
    // code to hide dialog box...
}
```

That's obviously a very specific selector but since we don't have much context I am not sure how much less specific you can get away with it being.  You could just as easily use `a.ui-dialog-titlebar-close` or `span.ui-icon-closethick` as your selector.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the class `ui-dialog-titlebar-close`